# Normalize nested blocks with jQuery or JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a block of HTML with nested headings, paragraphs etc.

Is there a jQuery/JavaScript plugin/function/snipet that can unnest them?, or how would I go about doing it?

I can supply a list of tags that should not be nested.

For example I have

```
<h1>
    Heading 1
    <h2>
        Heading 2
        <h3>
            Heading 3
        </h3>
    </h2>
</h1>

<p>
    Paragraph
    <p>
        Paragraph
    </p>
    <p>
        Paragraph
    </p>
</p>

<p>
    Paragraph
    <h1>
        Heading 1
        <h6>
            Heading 6
        </h6>
        Heading 1
    </h1>
    Paragraph
<p>
```

Which should respectively be converted to

```
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h2>Heading 2</h2>
<h3>Heading 3</h3>

<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>
<p>Paragraph</p>

<p>Paragraph<p>
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<h6>Heading 6</h6>
<h1>Heading 1</h1>
<p>Paragraph<p>
```

***Update:***

I have noticed the Firefox and Chrome at least does some automatic correction when the HTML is appended to the DOM. (as I have the HTML in a string, but can append it to he DOM if needed)

The only thing it does not do is remove `p` tags out of headings.

Comment: What browser you using? Firefox has sorted most of that for me.

Comment: @alex Firefox 9, and Chrome 15, old browsers are not really in my target audience.

Comment: I started some code that does a recursive look-up but can't finish it right now: http://jsfiddle.net/uBsX7/2/

Comment: @Petah: It's going to be difficult because at least some browsers already change the markup so it's valid. I tried iterating over all descendants of the parent elements, filtering elements of which their `display` property was set to `block``. Then turn that into a flat list and re-insert them.

Comment: @alex I had the HTML in a string, not on the DOM. So I see now that the browser does do some correction, which is good but the only thing I notice it does not do, is move p's out of headings

Comment: @Petah: You could code for that scenario. `$('p').filter(function() { return $(this).parent().is(':heading'); }).each(function() { $(this).insertAfter($(this).parent()); });`.

Comment: @alex, post a working answer and I might give you the tick. I also just found a way to do it using wrap (inspired by you first attempt at answering), which Ill post now too.

Comment: **[THIS](http://jsfiddle.net/dzejkej/rGAuX/)** is what I have so far. Splitting into multiple elements is not covered :-/.

Comment: @Petah: I've cleaned up that comment and posted it as an answer.

Comment: If you give a browser invalid HTML, all bets are off. If you are depending on browser error correction, you have a serious design flaw in your application - fix the HTML at the source.

Comment: @RobG, the source is user input in the form of a DOMFragment, so your point is moot.

Comment: @Petah - a DOM fragment is not markup, it is an object. Anyway, do you allow users to input invalid data for any other data entry fields? Why is HTML markup different? Browser error correction will likely not be consistent, you are making a rod for your own back.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most browsers will correct the DOM to be valid.

> So I see now that the browser does do some correction, which is good but the only thing I notice it does not do, is move `p`'s out of headings.

This code will move `p` elements to after their heading element.

```
$('p').filter(function() {
    return $(this).closest(':header').length;
}).each(function() {
    $(this).insertAfter($(this).closest(':header'));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rx3SD/).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
html = $('<' + tag + '>' + html + '</' + tag + '>');
html.find('p').wrapInner('<' + tag + '/>');
html.find('p > *').unwrap();
html = $('<div/>').html(html).html();
```

But its not an exact answer to my question, as it was a little hard to explain what I was really trying to do.